# Perl Regular Expression issues

Tags: regex, perl

how do I capture everything after T and everything before T using a regex.

What I have so far is only giving me the number 1.

```
 my $string = '2014-06-09T01:59:54.998Z';
 my $mystring = $string =~  m/T(.*)Z/;
```

I am not very well with regex.  I assumed this is getting anything between T and Z.  Tried leaving off the Z still prints 1.But it only prints

```
  1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
my ($date, $time) = split /T/, $string;
```

In your case, you forget to put your match in list context.

```
my ($mystring) = ($string =~  m/T(.*)Z/);
```

In scalar context, you get the number of captured substrings.